# Не получается подключиться к прокси

Tags: c#, .net, websocket, сокеты, прокси

Пытаюсь подключиться через веб сокеты к irc chat через прокси, и у меня не конектит к прокси почему то, без прокси все работает как надо.

```
var url = new Uri("ws://irc-ws.chat.twitch.tv:80");
var factory = new Func<ClientWebSocket>(() => new ClientWebSocket
{
    Options =
    {
        Proxy = new System.Net.WebProxy("23.239.20.205",80),
    }
});
 
var client = new WebsocketClient(url,factory);
client.Start();
client.Send("PASS oauth:xxx");
client.Send("NICK xxx");
client.Send("JOIN #xxx");
client.MessageReceived.Where(x => 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine(x.Text); 
    return true; 
}).Subscribe();
while (true)
{
    client.Send("PRIVMSG #xxx :" + Console.ReadLine());
}
```

Comment: А напрямую без прокси получается? Этот код содержит синтаксические ошибки, проверьте правильность того что вы вставили

Comment: Без прокси все работает отлично

Comment: так как в вопросе про это не написано ни слова, то можно сделать вполне очевидный вывод: автор пытается использовать «обыкновенный» http-прокси в качестве websocket-прокси. естественно, без [поддержки со стороны прокси-сервера](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html), ничего не получается.